# Is there any way to get the list of 'followers/'following' and 'messages' in my Twitter app in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, twitter

I am building a demo Twitter app. I have fetched the search results and timeline tweets. Is there any way to get the list of people I am following and my followers? And, can my messages be fetched too?

Comment: You should accept some answers before making new questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/friends/ids

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/followers/ids

Check this links to know the parameters to get the list of followers and know the REST API link for retrieve the friends and followers.

Comment: And what about the format we get calling these functions. They do not seem to be a .jason. So how to work with them. Plz brief. Thanks.

Comment: Ofcourse the response format will be in JSON only.. Check the Example request in that link. There will be a URL for that look like this " https://api.twitter.com/1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=twitterapi " with keyword in it as "json"

Comment: The friend query returns a list od IDs. How to get the information out of that id?

Comment: After you get the list of ids,you need to send a request again to get the info about those users using this request https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup

Comment: how do i get the followers names and following person names